# Join 2 tables by ID who from first table

Tags: sql, join, auto-increment

I have 2 tables, One with Auto Increment ID and the other with a column ID but no auto increment. I want IDs from the first table will be in the column ID of the second table.
I know Inner Join/ left/ right but it seems this is not what I really want.

Comment: Can you give sample data of the two tables and the desired output?

Comment: If you want IDs from the first table to restrict  ID values of the second table you want a FOREIGN KEY.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: table structure? sample input? sample output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from table_a a
inner join table_b b on a.auto_increment_id = b.column_id
```